# Mathematical Induction - Inequality

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, induction

Does anyone have any idea on how to complete the inductive step?

Thm: For all $n >= 0~~~~ 6^n + 4  > n^3$

Pf: by Induction
    Let $P(n)$ be proposition that $~6^n + 4  > n^3$

Base Case: $P(0)$ is true.
   $~~6^0 + 4  > 0^3$
   $~~5  > 0~~~$(proven!)

Inductive Step:
   For all $~~n >= 0$, show that $P(n) => P(n+1)$.
   Assume $P(n)$ is true for purposes of induction.
   (ie, assume $~~6^n + 4  > n^3$)
   Need to show that (6^(n+1))+4 $> (n+1)^3$
   $~~6^n + 4  > n^3$
   $~~6(6^n + 4)  > 6n^3$
     (6^(n+1))+4(6) $>6n^3$
     (6^(n+1))+4 $>6n^3-24+4$
     (6^(n+1))+4 $>6n^3-20$ (I'm stuck here...)

This theorem is self conjectured because I want to prove this on my own without any solutions present yet it seems that I can't prove it. I have already thought of any possible axioms that could help me but still no luck. Any ideas, tips or solutions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Try to start off with
$$6^{n+1} + 4 > 6n^3 + 4 > n^3 + 3n^2 + 3n + 1 = (n+1)^3$$
And wfind justification for the second estimate.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I don't understand what you want me to do because, based from what I've known about inequalities, I have to start off with the proposition which was assumed to be true and just manipulate it algebraically to prove the implication but based on your comment, it seems that there is another approach when dealing inequalities. Would you care to explain it further for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume:

$6^n + 4 > n^3$

Thus, we want to prove:

$6^{n+1} + 4 > (n+1)^3$

From the hypothesis:

$6^n > n^3-4 \rightarrow 6^{n+1} > 6n^3 -24$

It suffices to show that: $6n^3-24 > (n+1)^3$

Expanding gives: $5n^3-3n^2-3n-21$

We want to show that this is greater than zero. However, I don't want to find the roots. Thus, we let $n=1$ and see: $5-3-3-21 < 0$ So $n=1$ does not work. However, letting $n=2$ gives $40-12-6-21 > 0$ Thus, we take the derivative of $5n^3-3n^2-3n-21$ and get: 
$15n^2-6n-3$ Since the parabola open up, and letting $n=2$ is positive, we can see that the derivitive is greater than 0 for $n>2$ and thus the original function is greater than zero for $n \ge 2$ Thus, we have proved it for $n \ge 2$ Substituting in $n=1, 0$ gives the complete solution set

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have understood that we need to prove that function if it is greater than zero and n=2 proves that. However, I don't understand why we need to use derivative here. Further explaination is much more appreciated.

Comment: Sure. We know that for n=2 the function > 0. To show that this is true for n>2 we need to show that the function is increasing. If a function is increasing over a domain, then its derivative is > 0 over that domain. Thus, we wanted to show that the derivative is > 0 for the domain (2, infinity). Since we know the derivative is a parabola, and for n=2 the derivative is greater than zero, we can say that the derivative is greater than 0 for n>2. This implies that the function is increasing for n>2 and therefore it is >0 for n>2

Comment: Thank you very much. That was a very nice explaination. I understood it very well. Can I use additional base case like "prove P(1) is true." to fill in the missing link?

Comment: I would be careful; You have shown that if case n is true, then case n+1 is true. So what you have is the classic domino example. However, you need somewhere to start the domino chain, and that starting point is your base case; the induction only proves it for $n \ge 2$ so you can't claim that if case(n=1) is true then case(n=2) is true, because what we just proved is not true for n=1. So really,your base case would be n=2. You would start your proof by proving n=0 and n=1 and then proceed with the induction.A similar problem: $3^n > n^3$; there is a cleaner sol. in that problem, though.

Answer (score 0):

All you have left to prove is that $6n^3-20 \geq (n+1)^3$

So it's sufficient to prove that $5n^3-3n^2-3n-21 \geq 0$

Now, simply investigate the function $5n^3-3n^2-3n-21$:

- Find the derivative of the function
- Show that the only root of the function is at $n<2$
- Show that the function is monotonously increasing for $n\geq2$
- Hence $\forall{n\geq2}:5n^3-3n^2-3n-21 \geq 0$, Hence $\forall{n\geq2}:6^n+4 > n^3$

Finally, you've already shown that $6^n+4>n^3$ for $n=0$, so just show it for $n=1$...